# Python argparse with changing the parameters number

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to create a simple python with `argparse` flags. There are 2 arguments `A` and `B` and in case in aargument `A` the parameter that was entered was `A` it will ask for the 3rd parameter `C`.

- if in the first parameter `A` wasn't submitted it won't need to enter 3rd parameter
  My code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("A", help="A")
parser.add_argument("B", help="B")


args = parser.parse_args()

print("A:{} B:{}     ".format(
    args.A,
    args.B,
))

if args.a =="A":
    parser.add_argument("C", help="C")
    print(args.C)
```

Comment: Are these arguments positionals (as in your example) or optionals (as in the answer)?  Whether they are 'required' or not is specified in different ways.  And how they handle order also differs.  In either case I'd suggest making `C` not-required, and testing after parsing.  That's usually simpler than trying to do something fancy with in the parser itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--A", help="A")
parser.add_argument("--B", help="B")

opts, rem_args = parser.parse_known_args()
if opts.A:
    parser.add_argument("--C", required=True,type=int, help='C')
    # use options and namespace from first parsing
    parser.parse_args(rem_args, namespace = opts)
```

In this case whenever the argument `--A` is passed it will require also `--C`.

You can refer to the docs to understand [`parser.parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args).

Notice the `--C` won't appear in the help messege.

Example:

1. `so.py --B 1` - Works
2. `so.py --A 1 --B 1` - Don't Work
3. `so.py --A 1 --B 1 --C 1` - Works
4. `so.py --A 1 --C 1` - Works
5. `so.py --B 1 --C 1` - Works, but it's a don't care case so avoid it in the code logic.

Comment: but I need a case that if --A argument that was passed is equal to "A" it will require the argument of --C

Comment: I mean it's also ok to have 3 argsparse from the beginning, I just want that the 3rd one will be required just in case the first argument is equal to something ("A" or so).

Comment: @pythonmaniac so just implement it as logic in the code. You can condition the existence of an argument based on the value passed to other argument.

Comment: That's what i was trying to do in my code but with no success.

Comment: The help text that this generates doesn't include `--C`. The only way to know that `--C` is required is to not provide it when providing `--A`. This may be better implemented using [`sub-commands`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)

Answer (score 1):

In an `ipython` session:

```
In [1]: import argparse
In [2]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [3]: p.add_argument('A');
In [4]: p.add_argument('B');
In [5]: p.add_argument('C', nargs='?');    # optional positional

In [6]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] A B [C]

positional arguments:
  A
  B
  C

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

If only 2 are given, the last is default `None`:

```
In [7]: p.parse_args('foo bar'.split())
Out[7]: Namespace(A='foo', B='bar', C=None)
In [8]: p.parse_args('foo bar baz'.split())
Out[8]: Namespace(A='foo', B='bar', C='baz')
```

We can test `args.A` and raise an error is `C` is not given (its default):

```
In [9]: args = p.parse_args('A bar baz'.split())
In [10]: if args.A == 'A' and args.C is None:
    ...:     p.error('C is required')
    ...: 
In [11]: args = p.parse_args('A bar'.split())
In [12]: if args.A == 'A' and args.C is None:
    ...:     p.error('C is required')
    ...: 
usage: ipython3 [-h] A B [C]
ipython3: error: C is required
```

We could do something similar with `optionals/flagged` arguments.

While it's possible to do the `required` testing with a 2 stage parser, I think testing after parsing is simpler.

===

```
In [16]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [17]: p.add_argument('--A', required=True);
In [18]: p.add_argument('--B', required=True);
In [19]: p.add_argument('--C');
In [20]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] --A A --B B [--C C]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --A A
  --B B
  --C C
In [21]: args = p.parse_args('--A foo --B bar'.split())
In [22]: args
Out[22]: Namespace(A='foo', B='bar', C=None)
```